# Get "Microsoft.SqlServer.Wmi.ServiceState" in .NET 4.0 Application

Tags: c#, .net, sql, console, wmi

I'm connection to an Microsoft SQL Server 2008 in C# .NET 4.0 Application.
Now I want to display all sql Services from the remote computer.

```
ManagedComputer managedComputer = new ManagedComputer("ServerName", "Login", "Password");
foreach (var service in managedComputer.Services)
{
    Console.WriteLine(service.Name + " | " + service.ServiceState);
}
```

The problem is, that I can't build the solution because Visual Studio 2012 brings the error, I should add an Assembly. Here is the error message:

> *The type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ServiceState' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a
>   reference to assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.WmiEnum, Version=11.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'.*

Of course I added this assembly but still there is no change.

The problem comes from the Code **service.ServiceState**.

How can I fix this problem? Is this Assembly only for .NET 2.0?
Or is there any other way to get the status *(running, stopped...)* of an remote sql service?